# Acrescentar campo na posição que eu quero no sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Sempre que faço um `ALTER TABLE` e adiciono uma coluna, esse campo vai para o final.

Em modo design, usando a ferramenta gráfica do Sql Management, há a opção de Insert Column em qualquer posição, mas acontece que eu não consigo salvar.

Tenho permissão de Admnistrador do banco. Como eu faço, se é que há como, incluir em uma tabela já existente, inclusive com dados, colocar esse novo campo na posição que eu quero?

Comment: Dá algum erro para salvar? Você sabe que isto vai recriar toda a tabela e fazer outras manipulações na base?

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá? Pode ter uma configuração do Management Studio que estaria barrando isso (o erro indicaria qual).

Comment: Em realidade não dá erro, apenas uma mensagem de que não é possível fazer a alteração, somente se eu dropar a tabela e etc. Agora não entendi o downvote. A pergunta é direta e apenas uma resposta, gostaria de entender esses caras aqui dentro do forum.

Answer (score 4):

Como já foi dito, esse tipo de alteração exige que a tabela seja recriada. Você precisa autorizar o Management Studio a fazer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Origem da imagem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12582648/825789

Comment: Importante comentar que isso só é possível no modo gráfico e recriar tabelas gigantes é inviável. Por fim isso é só uma alteração estética, para o SQL Server a disposição das colunas não muda em nada.

Comment: Isso não impede o trampo. Era só uma questão estética mesmo. Recriar, significa perder tudo e isso não posso fazer, logo vou deixar como está mesmo.

Comment: Acho que você não perde os dados, mas a operação pode ser lenta @pnet.

Comment: Será que não perco? Vou fazer um teste com uma tabela em casa somente e ver se realmente eu não perco os dados. Se for assim, está resolvido a questão, outrossim, continua valendo.

Comment: Você pode criar uma tabela qualquer só pra testar isso....

Answer (score 2):

**Normalmente, o erro aparece quando você tenta alterar a estrutura de uma tabela que já está sendo utilizada e tem alguma referência, seja de FK, Constraint, Index, etc...**

Abaixo, listo duas opções que podem ser adotadas:

- Se não houver muitos dados em sua tabela, você pode exportar, dropar a tabela atual, criar a tabela nova, editar os valores exportados e inserir com os valores na ordem com sua nova coluna junto.
- Caso você tenha muitos registros em sua tabela, sugiro que você deixe a coluna no fim da tabela mesmo, não irá afetar em nada, só não irá visualizar tão facilmente, quando retornar um select direto no Management Studio.

Answer (score -1):

sei que faz tempo, mas descobri com se faz tal proeza

-- excluí a tabela anterior

```
drop table cta_receber_recebimentos_backup
go
```

-- aqui coloque os campos que queria e na ordem que eu queria, e fiz um backup da tabela

```
SELECT ID, NR_TITULO, DT_PAGAMENTO, TIPO_DOC, VL_SALDO, VL_JUROS, VL_MULTA, VL_DESCONTO, VL_PAGO, VL_SALDO_ATUAL, CXA_CODIGO, USUARIO  
INTO CTA_RECEBER_RECEBIMENTOS_BACKUP 
FROM CTA_RECEBER_RECEBIMENTOS
go
```

-- visualizei se estava tudo certo

```
select * from cta_receber_recebimentos_backup
go
```

-- aqui exclui a tabela, anterior

```
drop table cta_receber_recebimentos 
go
```

-- um novo backup, porem do _backup para a tabela original

```
select * into CTA_RECEBER_RECEBIMENTOS 
from cta_receber_recebimentos_backup
go
```